# How to Delete Range of Lines in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace

I am trying to delete multiple range of files.
Mu file contains 1000s of lines, and I want to delete line 70-500, line 600-100 like this, in PowerShell,

I tried `-replace`, but it's not working.

Trying to replace line index value 9 to 10:

```
(cat test.txt) -replace (cat test.txt)[9..10],"" | sc test.txt -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ReadCount` property `Get-Content` adds to the output:

```
Get-Content 'test.txt' | Where-Object {
    -not ($_.ReadCount -ge 70 -and $_.ReadCount -le 500) -and
    -not ($_.ReadCount -ge 600 -and $_.ReadCount -le 1000)
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be a tad more obvious to use a range & the `-notin` operator? that would also let you avoid the need for negating the filter ... i get confused too easily when dealing with negated matches. [*blush*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Perhaps more obvious, but also significantly slower b/c `-notin` does a linear search on an array.

Comment: ah! thank you for that info ... i never tested it before. [*grin*]

Comment: thank you @AnsgarWiechers, it worked, this is what I was looking for